# Java relative positioning swing components in an undecorated jframe in java form

Tags: java, swing, position, center

I need to create a login interface that opens in full screen(working in all display resolutions) but with undecorated(true).
I could create the expected jframe but how can i position swing components in the center of the jframe?
here is what I need to get
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3-1tpHz8_TGU1p3SlA2UGMxekk/edit?usp=sharing
and this is adaptive to all screen sizes

Comment: For this use BorderLayout and assign the alignment to CENTER of Swing components.

Comment: @NadunLiyanage Totally unrelated to this question, you deleted your recent question before I could answer it. Set the container background to `null` to revert to inherited default. Sorry about hijacking this question.

Comment: Thank you very much mr Jason...I did the same thing you said... it was working again thank you so much for your feedback.... and im sorry for the inconvenience caused...

Answer (score 3):

An undecorated frame is still a frame. In fact you could simply use a `JWindow`.

What this means is, decorated or otherwise, you can layout your components as per normal.  Because your pushing for full screen, I might suggest using something like `GridBagLayout` as a bases, but that's me.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses... Here Im new in java and I think that the question was not clear... Here is the thing I need to do.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3-1tpHz8_TGU1p3SlA2UGMxekk/edit?usp=sharing
![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Yes, and. This seems simple enough for GridBagLayout to a eve quite well

Answer (score 0):

use the setBounds() method

```
setLayout(null);
setBounds(int x,int y,int width,int height);
```

setBounds() method will place the components in the desired position of the JFrame window.

Comment: In 15 years of professional Swing development, I never found a reason to use a null layout, a given the problems of font metrics, dpi and other rendering differences between platforms makes this a incredibly difficult and error prone solution - just saying

Comment: *"use the setBounds() method"*  ..unless of course, you want a *reliable and robust* GUI.  Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Answer (score 0):

Use Border Layout,This layout will help you to assign components to center.

For example:`

```
Frame.add(GuiFieldsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Or

```
Frame.add(GuiButtonsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);        
Frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: In your second line `GuiButtonsPanel` will replace `GuiFieldsPanel` at `BorderLayout.CENTER` position. `BorderLayout` can lay out just a single component in each location.

Comment: NorderLayout will only allow a a single component to occupy any one of its 5 available positions, this means, you can't have to two components occupying the CENTER position

Comment: Ohh..sorry for mistake.i will correct the answer..thanks for suggestion.